# How to link php files in main directory to a files from "include" folder?

Tags: php, href

How to link php-files, which are at Wamp www-directory, to a files which are at "includes" folder?

So I basically have a php-file with some content (name: blocks.php) included to my index.php file and it is placed to "includes" folder. But as this blocks.php file also has some elements with a href, which should link to a files what are placed to main folder(www) - for example file named populars.php - the direct linking (a href="populars.php") does not work as they are not in the same folder.

Also "../populars.php" or "projectname/populars.php" is not found. So whats the right way to do this?

Comment: `/projectname/populars.php` I suppose your `populars.php` is in the project root? then you need a trailing slash before the `projectname`

Comment: yep, that did the trick, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/` to indicate the `root` directory of your project.

In this case, `/projectname` is your project's folder.
So to access `populars.php` from a file inside a folder in your project, you should indicate the root directory then navigate to the folder where you put your file.

your `populars.php` is placed on the root directory of your project, so:
`/projectname/populars.php`

This will also work like so:
`/projectname/js/init.js` or `/projectname/css/base.css`